# How use a -ms-expand in GWT (Google Web Tolkit)

Tags: css, gwt

I want to delete arrow in select element.
I use CSS rules like

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

But GWT not understand this rules. Who can help me? How to fix it?

Comment: That's because `-ms-` means that rule is Microsoft specific - you are trying to use it with Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolve this problem.

Escape the colons to make it work:

```
select:\:\-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```